# Understanding Shabsai Tzvi

Tags: history, historical-figures, messiah, shabbetai-tzvi

Who was Shabsai Tzvi and why was he considered evil?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/110/3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Shabtai Tzvi was a Sefardic Jew who grew up in Turkey, became very learned, but eventually became a false Messiah. Whether he himself was bad or not is a matter of debate. In his biography/history of Shabtai Tzvi, Professor Gershon Scholem presents a very strong case that Shabtai suffered from Bi-polar disorder, a mental illness that produces extreme mood swings. It seems most likely that his "prophet", Natan of Gazza was evil and used him for his fantasies and honor.

It could be as an eminent Jewish Historian once said "Shabtai Tzvi was a Talmid Chochom who was Meshugah."

Even though he did horrible *avairos*, if he indeed was *meshugah* (mentally unstable) where is the evil in that? The fact that Natan and others helped him fool most of the Jewish Diaspora does not make Shabtai himself an evil person.

Comment: At most, he was sometimes a shoteh and other times normal. According to halachah, he would have been fully responsible for his actions during the times when he was normal (Shulchan Aruch, Even Ha'ezer 121:3). And during those times, he could have repudiated his actions, and the "prophecies" of Natan and so forth; that he failed to do so makes him a rasha. Furthermore, what about his anti-halachic actions from long before he met Natan, such as pronouncing the Shem Hameforash?

Comment: Once again, it is not so simple to say that when one who has bipolar disorder is in his good mood, that is a time in which he is considered halachically normal. Scholem's descriptions of Shabtai, based on actual accounts give the impression that Shabtai had fits of insanity during his up moods as well. I am sure there is discussion about such issues  in Halachic responsa, especially dealing with divorces.

Comment: Somehow, Scholem will bend over backwards to exonerate Shabbesai Tzvi himself, but on the other hand will bend over backwards in the other direction to accuse Gedolei Yisroel of being secret Sabbateans, on the flimsiest of evidence, if any at all! I'm none too sure his opinions are worth much in this context, frankly.

Comment: I agree with you regarding Scholem's efforts to not talk the party-line regarding the Shabtai Tzvi affair and its aftermath. However, in the interest of our own intellectual honesty, if you study the sources regarding Shabtai himself you can definitely walk away with the impression that Shabtai was a tool. He had no significant following until Natan got ahold of him.

Comment: My impression is that Scholem in his Shabtai Tzvi biography is a very different Scholem from his later writings on the Rav Emden - Rav Eibschetz, or Maharam Hagiz - Ramhal controversies. One possible reason is because the biography (in the edition that I have) was published and marketed as a book for not only the academic "elite". His writings on those controversies had a smaller audience and he pushed his agendas and said much more controversial statements in them about Gedolei Yisrael. But I can see why you would not want to accept his conclusions.

Comment: ... his conclusions about Shabtai considering what he says about the Gedolim. I still think it is a bit more nuanced of an issue than that, even if we lay Scholem aside as an authority. Shabtai did one horrible thing and was exiled from Smyrna with virtually no following. There is also little evidence to suggest that Shabtai revealed any messianic delusions at that point. Only when he met Natan do we see him develop a following and creating a messianic movement.

Comment: When I said an "eminent Jewish Historian", I did not mean Scholem. I meant my father who besides for being a respected Talmid Hochom and educator, taught a course in Jewish History for many years at one of the major Othodox Rabbinical Colleges in North America, and  has written important reviews on various major Jewish History publications.

Comment: There's no question that without Natan Ha'azati, Shabbesai Tzvi wouldn't have been able to do nearly as much damage to the Jewish world as he did. But that's not really the point.

Comment: If you'll forgive the comparison, it's like considering what Hitler (yimach shmo) might have been without a Wehrmacht to do his bidding; he'd still have been the same evil Jew-hater, he just wouldn't have been able to carry out his plans. In somewhat the same way, S.T. already had shown, by the time he met up with N., that shemiras hamitzvos meant little or nothing to him; that his ideas didn't spread further at the time was because he lacked a megaphone, not because he had a conscience.

Comment: I respect what your father says. But again, so what? Again, to continue with the comparison, Hitler was likely insane too. Doesn't make his actions any less damaging, or wicked.

Comment: That "S.T. already had shown, by the time he met up with N., that shemiras hamitzvos meant little or nothing to him" is a claim based on what evidence? That Hitler was insane is simply untrue. He was sane enough to formulate his wicked hatred into an evily brilliant piece of literature depicting his "struggle". That Shabtai did something to compell the Bais Din of Smyrna to expell him before he ever met Natan is probably true. That he did it maliciously and with his right mind is possible but based on subsequent descriptions of his personality, unlikely.

Comment: As I said before, it is not an aveirah to be a mushuganah. Hitler was never described as a mushuganah. That he had a temper and tantrums that bordered on manic is true, but he was always in his right albeit evil mind. Insane and evil can be distinguished based on a person's history. Hitler functioned in a way that mental health professionals, or for that matter, the Torah would consider sane behavior before his political career. Later, he had "rational" reasons for his actions and gathered henchmen around him to hatch his evil plans.

Comment: Shabtai, on the other hand, seems to have dropped his messianic and antinomian behaviors until Natan Ha'Azzati tells him that he had a prophecy concerning Shabtai's messianic status. The trith is that unless we could put Shabtai in a room and analyze his behavior we will be going in circles, but the Hitler comparison is a difficult one. Read Shirer's biographical sketches of Hitler and you will not be reading about insanity, but evil.

Comment: BTW, Rav Ruderman told my father that equating "Rish'us" (evil) with insanity is a form of effort at mitigation of the nature of evil itself. (He did not say it in English-but that is the best translation I can come up with.) He went on to say that one can distinguish between the 2 based on where it started. He gave the example of the case of the 2 harlots fighting over the baby in front of King Shlomo. Was the one who said "Yes! Cut the baby in half!" crazy? No, because she started with the claim that the baby was her's, proving that her motivation was jealousy.

Comment: Ultimately jealousy says "If I cannot have it, then she cannot either!" As insane as cutting the baby in half sounds, her initial evil jealousy locked her in to a world view that made sense to her. That is evil. Read up on Hitler and you get such a picture. Within his experiences and influences his conclusions seem to him and the people of his society as rational and reasonable conclusions while to an outsider they seem quite barbaric and yes, even insane. But it is not generated by insanity.

Comment: When one studies Shabtai, it is hard to conclude evil considering that he pulled a pretty wacky and delusional stunt before he even had the backing of a society or following to support it. Quite different than the Hitler picture.

Comment: Please do a little more research on Hitler before you diagnose him as insane. William Shirer's writings are an excellent place to start. He definitely had a troubled upbringing but insanity was not one of his traits. The acts that evil people perpetrate are definitely horrific beyond belief, but what leads them to those acts is what determines if it is evil or insanity. A subtle, yet crucial difference.

Comment: BTW, I have been playing devil's advocate. As I said in my answer "Whether he himself was bad or not is a matter of debate." I was just suggesting that it is still a matter of debate that is probably unresolvable. One reason that it is hard to get an accurate picture of what happened in the ST affair is because there were Gedolei Yisrael who were fooled or were at least neutral and reserved their judgment on Shabtai until he converted. Afterwards there was understandably an "I told you so!" attitude by the few who did oppose the movement and there was an effort to bury much of the saga ...

Comment: to protect the emunas hachomim of the masses. Communication was not great in those days and rumors were flying in all directions. Needless to say, one great way to disassociate the movement from Gedolim was to focus blame on the evil perpetrators. This was a necessary P.R. damage control/Hillul Hashem prevention on the part of our great leaders. This has nothing to with Scholem's accusing "Gedolei Yisroel of being secret Sabbateans" as you are referring to his belief regarding later Gedolei Yisrael such as the Rebbe Reb Yonason Eibschetz, Zecher Tzaddik V'Kadosh L'vracha.

Comment: The fact is that there were Gedolim who were unfortunately fooled and the mess needed to be cleaned up especially with the rise of such sects as the Donmeh who were converting to Islam and remaining Sabbateans. So this leaves us with very little accurate information regarding the key players. With what little we have Scholem makes a strong case but you could argue otherwise. We'll have to wait for the complete truth ... B'karov B'Yameinu...

Comment: I have to strongly disagree. Someone who is bi-polar who causes great harm to others, physically or spiritually, can be regarded as a bad person. The fact that he was used or the fact that he was (perhaps) mentally unstable does not mean that he deserves a pass. Perhaps any physical punishment can be weighed against his disability. But when history judges the damage he caused, he should be remembered as a false prophet (bad, per the Torah) and someone who led others to sin (bad), and publicly sinned himself (bad).

Comment: He was known (according to Scholem's sources) as a Talmid Chochom in Rav Chagiz's yeshiva in Yerushalayim. He was considered respected enough to represent the Kehilla of Yerushalayim when he was sent on a mission to Egypt, to collect funds for them.

Comment: (ping @ShmuelBrin i assume for the last comment)

Answer (score 2):

He was a false Messiah,he was Bad because mainly he said Certain mitzvos did not exist he was famous for making up the Bracha Mattir Haissurim and in the end he Converted to Islam

Comment: He never said that certain mitzvos did not exist. He said that certain mitzvos were no longer applicable.

Comment: Joseph, its amazing sometimes how you make such diyukim and other times not.

Comment: I was not trying to defend Shabtai, has veshalom, just commenting in the interest of historical accuracy. Please point out a diyuk I missed, I always want to improve.

Comment: YS, I mean that sincerely.

Comment: Unless you mean I am being too particular. In that case, historical accuracy is under such attack in this age of revisionism that one must be very careful.

Comment: I wouldn't categorize him as a false messiah - he was a failed messiah.  A false messiah is one who was never eligible to become messiah in the first place.  A failed messiah is a sincere Jew who really thinks that he could be "it".  Strictly speaking, since Islam is not avodah zarah, one could convert to Islam to save his life.  The sultan, sensing a threat to his power, told Shabtai to convert or die.  Therefore, Shabtai didn't necessarily do anything wrong in that regard.  Perhaps he could have been moshiach, but the generation wasn't worthy of him.

Comment: @Yahu, I know you're not around here anymore, but I'm responding to you anyway. How is claiming certain Mitzvoth are not applicable not a bad thing?

Comment: @user1095 By any measure he was a false messiah. He was not a failed messiah. I don't recall any literature supporting the idea of a failed messiah. One could argue that any great sage was/is a failed messiah, in that despite being great his potential as such was never realized. The Gemara mentions that Hizkiyahu _could have been_ messiah, but he wasn't. He was actually a king and he actually accomplished some of the things the messiah is supposed to do. But I wouldn't even classify _him_ as a failed messiah because it's not really something at which one can fail, if you think about it.

Comment: @Seth J , I'm around once in a while. I did not write that claiming mitzvos as not applicable anymore is not bad. I was merely correcting SimchasTorah's claim in the spirit of historical accuracy.

Comment: @Yahu Whoa! I did not see that coming! Thank you for your response. I see that you did not write that. I guess that I was reading your correction here as being a part of your answer (with which I strongly disagree, as I stated there). Forgive me this error. I like reading your posts. Ever think of coming back and contributing more?

Answer (score 2):

He was a Jew living in the 1600's who [claimed to be Moshiach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbatai_Zevi#Claims_of_messiahship)

To contrast with Yahu's answer.

He did many sins publicly including violating arayos (sexual sin) which is one of the 3 major sins which a person is supposed to martyr themselves for rather than transgress.  Whatever his status mentally he was clearly in enough control to promote himself as the messiah even after he converted to Islam. This gigantic chillul Hashem (desecration of God's name) caused countless Jews to lose their faith and either convert or abandon Judaism.

Comment: I addressed the issue of whether being in control of one's faculties is equted with sanity in the comments on my answer. In short: He had a history of mental illness and he had the strong encouragement, if not pressure, from Moslem officials and clerics to convert Jews. if he had started out normal then I would be in total agreement with you. Because he did not start out normal I leave whether Hashem judged him as a Rasha in Hashem's hands.